# Duplicate ID generation in ngForOf - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular10

I am using ngForOf to list dates, each date is represented by `id` property which is actually its index + 1. All the dates are present in form of object in an array. Also, each date is a component instance.

The thing with ngForOf is that whenever I delete a date from the list, the whole DOM refreshes and the ID's are assigned all over again.

```
<app-date *ngFor="let date of dates | callback: filterDates; index as i" (delete)="del(i)"></app-date>
```

**The Problem**

Now when I say "delete", I am not splicing/removing the date from the array, but setting the `action` property of the date to `"deleted"`. This is so that I don't have to make HTTP requests for every date to delete it from the database.

Once the `action` is `"deleted"`, the date does not show up in the DOM, but is still present in the array. So the next time DOM refreshes, it is going to reassign the IDs and now I am going to have duplicate ID's in the array. This has many consequences, the biggest one being that I cannot delete the dates with the same ID.

I also tried to change ID of the date on every delete event but that also messes up the array.

**Important**

I am aware of `trackBy`, but I don't understand how I can apply it to solve this problem and don't see a problem on the internet that relates to this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should just delete the date of your dates array and you don't make the http request. The list will update and there will be no more duplicate. Still fail to see how your dates can have the same unique identifier if you get them from your database thought. If you ever need to delete the dates in the database, you just have to use your array at last.

Comment: If I delete the date and send it to the server, it would not know which date specifically was deleted, which one was modified and which one is a new addition. If I follow this approach, I'd first need to delete all the dates that belong to that particular user and add again in the modified form. - Leccho

Comment: Any stackblitz DEMO could help us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

- **Background**

There are basically two arrays, one is the `dates` array through which I am traversing to render dates, the other array is the one that contains the DOM elements that represent each date that is showed on the screen. Angular does not care about what `id` or index the the date has in the `dates` array present in the component.ts file. By default, it tracks each element in the `ngFor` loop through index in the DOM array. This array keeps changing for every add/remove operation that occurs.

The mistake I made was that I used the DOM array index as the `id` of the date. Now due to the removal of any date, the DOM array was refreshing, and since I was never actually deleting or splicing the date from the array, there were always some duplicate `id`'s in the array.

- **Solution**

There should be a separate ID generation function, or maybe simply a number type property that keeps incrementing on every `pushDate()` operation. This will, to some extent, solve the problem of `id` duplication. Although, Angular still does not care about the `id` and it can only identify each date element by its index in the DOM array, so, in order to delete a specific date you need its index in the DOM array.

```
<app-date *ngFor="let date of dates | callback: filterDates; index as i" [id]="dateID" (delete)="del(i, $event)"></app-date>
```

Now, `(delete)` will return a string that shows the date, for example: 2020-8-15. This date, along with `action` property of that specific date will identify the date to be set to `deleted`. Here is how I do it:

```
getArrayIndex = (index: number, date: string): number => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dates.length; i++) {
        if(i == index && date == this.dates[i]['date']) {
            if(this.dates[i]['action'] == 'deleted') {
                return this.getArrayIndex(i + 1, date);
            }
            else {
                return i;
            }
        }
        else if(i == index && date != this.dates[i]['date']) {
            return this.getArrayIndex(i + 1, date);
        }
        else if(i != index) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

del = (num: number, event: string) => {
    let i = this.getArrayIndex(num, event);
    this.dates[i]['action'] = 'deleted';
}
```

The `del` function first finds the correct index of the date that is to be deleted in the `dates` array through `getArrayIndex()`. Once the `date` is found the `action` property of that particular date object is set to `"deleted"`.